# Picklist - Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, controller

I need to create records based on picklist selection type in Custom object.i did in this way.Once we are select Student then create new Application object and select employee also create new Application object.please say to me how to get input fields after change picklist.

Controller:

```
public class ApplicationdetailsController
{
   public Application__c applist {get; set;}
  public string selectedValue{get;set;}


  public ApplicationdetailsController()
  {
     applist = new Application__c();
     selectedValue='';
  }

  public List<selectoption> getoptions()
  {
   List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
   options.add(new SelectOption('--Select--','--Select--'));
   options.add(new SelectOption('Student','Student'));
   options.add(new SelectOption('Employee','Employee'));
   return options;
  }


  public pagereference save()
  {
    if(selectedValue == 'Student')
    {
    insert applist;
    }else if(selectedValue == 'Employee')
    {

    }
   return null;
 }
}
```

Visualforce:

```
<apex:page controller="ApplicationdetailsController">
 <apex:form >
  <apex:pageBlock >
               <apex:pageBlockSection >
              Select Application Details: <apex:selectList value="{!selectedValue}" size="1">
                              <apex:selectOptions value="{!options}"></apex:selectOptions>
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!save}" reRender="one" />
                </apex:selectList>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

           <apex:inputField value="{!applist.name}"/>
           <apex:pageblockButtons >
           <apex:commandButton value="Save Student" action="{!save}"/>
           </apex:pageblockButtons>


        </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. What are the input fields you need?

Comment: @Martin Lezer,First we are select Student on picklist Then get Firstname, Lastname email fields from Application custom object and next we are change and select Employee on picklist then get the Name,Email,CheckBox fields from same Application Custom Object.Like that create multiple Application Records in the same page

Comment: Your `actionSupport` shouldn't be doing a save operation, it needs to rerender the one of two different `apex:outputPanels` that contain the relevant inputFields based on picklist choice. Please use [edit] to amend your question